# How to add bottom tab navigator to one screen inside stack navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm making an app, and in the app there is a home screen. On the home screen, I want to add a bottom navigator with various logos, which when clicked on, navigate the user to a different screen. I only want the bottom navigator to be on the screens that can be accessed from the bottom navigator in home. How would I do this? Would I need different types of navigators in my app.js since I'm using a stack navigator as well? Thanks for any help, I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tab-based-navigation provided by react-navigation. Make tab navigator with the screens that you want to be displayed with tab and wrap that in Stack. Any other screen that you want to display without tab navigation, just add as another stack and wrap all the stacks in Stack.Navigator. Here's the docs they are pretty well explained
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it, it means a lot to me. Thank you!